# How to subscribe to two API's in canActivate Guard

Tags: angular

I am trying to chain two observables in one canActivate Guard.
But I am getting the folowing error in vs code:

```
Type 'Observable<boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>>' 
is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'.
```

Following is my code:

(Ignore the fact that i am subscribing to same api as its not available to me for time being. But the Implementation is the same way.)

```
canActivate(
    act_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt_token');
    if (token) {
      if (!this._auth.isTokenExpired(token)) {
        if (act_route.data.userType) {
          return this.checkUserType(act_route);
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        this._auth.userOut();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      this._auth.userOut();
      return false;
    }
  }

  checkUserType(act_route: any): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this._auth.checkUserType().pipe(
      map(
        res => {
          if (act_route.data.userType.includes(res)) {
            if (!act_route.data.permissionByPass && res !== 'SuperAdmin') {
              return this.checkAccess(act_route);
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          } else {
            this._route.navigate(['403']);
            return false;
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }

  checkAccess(act_route: any): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this._auth.checkUserType().pipe(
      map(
        res => {
          if (act_route.data.userType.includes(res)) {
            if (!act_route.data.permissionByPass && res !== 'SuperAdmin') {
              return true;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          } else {
            this._route.navigate(['403']);
            return false;
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

What should I do? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: use a switchmap instead of a map for the next 2 functions

Comment: If you have the codes on stackblitz someone can look into it as well